# Lusca csrf not working as expected - http request using old token

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, lusca

I was trying to set up CSRF protection with lusca on my Express.js application. Not it looks like this:

```
this.app.use(lusca({
      csrf: {
        cookie: {name: '_csrf'}
      },
      hsts: { maxAge: 31536000, includeSubDomains: true, preload: true },
      nosniff: true,
      referrerPolicy: "same-origin",
      xframe: "SAMEORIGIN",
      xssProtection: true,
    }));
```

And on client side as follow:

```
const res = await axios.post(`${Constants.apiUrl()}/${Constants.paths.login}`, 
                credentials, {
                    withCredentials: true,
                    xsrfCookieName: '_csrf'
                });
```

On the server-side, I also set some headers to be able to send cookies with request - `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')`.

Probably I'm missing some important part of how CSRF protection works. Now each time with the response, I'm getting new `csrf token` but this means that my new HTTP POST request sending the previous token that already outdated.
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem after testing for 3 hours. You need to add the `secret` of the csrf. Also, if you are using Angular, you need to add `angular: true` into the csrf.

```
this.app.use(lusca({
    csrf: {
        cookie: {name: '_csrf'},
        secret: 'qwerty'
    },
    hsts: { maxAge: 31536000, includeSubDomains: true, preload: true },
    nosniff: true,
    referrerPolicy: "same-origin",
    xframe: "SAMEORIGIN",
    xssProtection: true,
}));
```